# How do I find out what is causing this very wide table?

Tags: html, css

Lately, I've been running into more and more poorly designed websites that do things like this [Hudson Website](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Home)  The page is some 1600 pixels wide on my 90 degree rotated monitor, it means you have to scroll left<->right a LOT.  Having firebug installed, I figured I'd just go fix it on the fly for reading, but that is proving harder than imagined.

I can't seem to locate what is causing it to be so wide.  There is a `<table width='100%'>`, but that should be 100% of the container, and I can't find a container that says "BE UNREASONABLY WIDE".  So, I'm asking what tricks you use in firebug to figure out what is causing an element to have the size it has, specifically the width.

Edit:

Well, I'm still picking at it, and it turns out that

```
.wiki-content p {
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 850px;  // I had to add this to make it readable, width was NOT defined
}
```

will make it readable, so something about the `<p>` tag is causing it, but I don't see anything in the css that should make it this wide.  What am I missing?

Comment: If you are just wanting to view other peoples websites then Opera's "Fit to width" option does the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page is wide because of the `<pre>` elements.
At least on Firefox, you can fix it by adding the CSS rule:

```
pre {white-space:normal;}
```

Comment: How did you figure this out?  Just something you know to look for, or do you have some quick way of finding it in firebug?

Comment: Nothing special. I noticed the paragraph text overflows out of the background color, so I looked there, but couldn't find anything with a width. The next choice is a wide element, and the `<pre>` elements seemed suspicious.

Comment: One way is to load up the page, then start deleting nodes systematically (e.g., delete half the TRs, then half of the remainders, etc.). Eventually the page will "pop" back to a proper layout, and you have your culprit.

Comment: Speaking for myself, I was looking for anything non-wrappable, such as a really long link (with no spaces), or in this case a long stretch of code. Since `pre` elements do not wrap lines by default, it was the obvious culprit.

Comment: @Ken Redler: I call it *binary surgery*

Comment: @RedFilter, isn't that spelled *binary searchery*?

Answer (score 0):

You could run the page through a validator as a first step. E.g. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: My oh my at the things browsers will tolerate

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.hudson-ci.org%2Fdisplay%2FHUDSON%2FHome&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: 99.9% of websites fail validation and do not have this problem. I don't think this first step is useful.

Comment: A page can be valid and wide. `:)`

Comment: @moogoo : your logic escapes me.

Comment: Logic: if you try to troubleshoot random webpages by running them through the HTML nazi, you will quickly go insane. If you then try running the Javascript through jslint, you might want to keep a gun handy.

Comment: @moogoo: if you're troubleshooting random webpages you're already insane.

Comment: "Troubleshooting random webpages" is basically the modus operandi of Stackoverflow. This place *is* an insane asylum.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, I ran the [master CSS](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/s/1634/1/1.0/_/download/batch/confluence.web.resources%3amaster-styles/confluence.web.resources%3amaster-styles.css) of the linked site through [the Flumpcakes optimizer](http://flumpcakes.co.uk/css/optimiser/), and got this result:

```
Before 64064 
After 53832 
Saving 10232 
Percentage: 16%
```